# How to pass a List<user-defined object> to a constructor

Tags: c#, list, generics, constructor, arguments

I am new to C#...

I am attempting to pass objects between forms using the 'Constructor Method'

Here is the constructor for the called/invoked class:

```
public frmPeripheralOptions(List<PeriphItem> PeriphSelect)
{
    // code...
}
```

Here is the invoking code:

```
frmPeripheralOptions PeriphForm = new frmPeripheralOptions(PeriphSelect);
```

These are the compile-time errors that I receive at the above line:
C# won't let me insert the `PeriphSelect` as a parameter to the constructor.

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'BingP3.frmPeripheralOptions.frmPeripheralOptions(System.Collections.Generic.List)'
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\scott\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\BingP3\BingP3\frmComputerOrder.cs   200 47  BingP3
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' C:\Users\scott\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\BingP3\BingP3\frmComputerOrder.cs    200 72  BingP3

Here is the definition of the list.  It is identically defined in both classes:

```
public struct PeriphItem
{
    public int pos;
    public int qty;
    public string entry;
}

public System.Collections.Generic.List<PeriphItem> PeriphSelect { get; set; }
```

The list is initialized in the calling class default constructor as follows:

```
PeriphSelect = new List<PeriphItem>();
```

The goal here is to be able to access the same iteration of the `PeriphSelect` List from both classes.

I have successfully passed lists to constructors in this current project, but they were lists of standard objects such `List<Int> and`List`, but not lists of user-defined objects.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inference the type when creating the list.
Here would be the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class frmPeripheralOptions
{
    public frmPeripheralOptions(List<PeriphItem> periphSelect)
    {
        this.PeriphSelect = periphSelect;
    }
    public List<PeriphItem> PeriphSelect { get; set; }
}

public static Main(string[] args)
{
    var periphList = new List<PeriphItem>();
    var form = new frmPeripheralOptions(periphList);
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You treat any object the same, whether it be a system-provided one or one you created. Objects are objects. You want to create a List and tell it to treat is as a List of whatever. Ex:

```
private List<YourClass> myList = new List<YourClass>();
```

Or, since you are initialising it elsewhere (which I don't see much point to)...

```
private List<YourClass> myList;
public Constructor()
{
    myList = new List<YourClass>();
}
```

And when you pass it to the other class, you also have to tell it what kind of values it has in it, like so:

```
void Invoker()
{
    YourNewClass newClass = new YourNewClass(myList); // the same list you earlier defined.
}
// your new class:
public YourNewClass(List<YourClass> l)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Hope this was what you were looking for! :)